# Crop Picture into a Circular format Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, crop

I would like to crop the images into a circular format. Actually when I select the image it gives me the option to crop and it gives me a circular crop but when I save the image it still gives it to me in a square shape with the rest of the image. I've searched everywhere but nothing works for me. Here is my code:

```
Future<File?> _cropImage(File image) async {
File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper().cropImage(
sourcePath: image.path,
aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
compressQuality: 50,
cropStyle: CropStyle.circle,
);
return croppedFile;
}
```

I tried to Crop pictures into a circular shape in Flutter but it crops it into a square shape.

Comment: where do you displaying this image after cropping ? I mean in widget Container or SizedBox